# Vertical ActionBar for individual fragments

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm looking to add a vertical equivalent to the top ActionBar in Honeycomb going along the right side of the app, similar to the Google Talk and Superuser apps. Is there a standard way to accomplish this, or did these apps deal with it on their own?

Comment: Looking at the Superuser app's source ([here](https://github.com/ChainsDD/Superuser) for the curious), it's a vertical layout of ImageButtons with the background set to that of the right panel. So no builtin menu solution, but not difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I assume they dealt with it on their own. Thats what I ended up doing with a nav bar in addition to the actiobar..